# What is the distance of a 5 feet tall object which appears 1 inch tall

Tags: geometry

There are similar questions I have found, but the answers are either in requests for clarification or for formulas which require the distance to be known or other things which leave the question unanswered or unanswerable.

For specifics, I have a miniature production of an item which at 1:60 scale is 1" tall. Its real-life counterpart is 5' tall.
If the actual real-life item were placed at a distance away from the miniature such that both items appeared to be exactly the same height, how far away from the miniature would the real-life item be?

For further clarification, the miniature is item A, the real item is item B.
A is located at point x, B is located at point y. the distance from x to y is z.
A is 1" tall at x. B is 5' tall at x. B is 1" tall (apparently) at y.
What is (how do I calculate) the distance z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real-life item has to be $60$ times as far away from the viewer as the miniature to look the same size, i.e. at a distance of $60x$ where $x$ is the distance of the minature. The distance between the real-life item and the minature is therefore $60x-x=59x$.

Comment: so if I am 2 feet away from the miniature the real item must be 118 feet from me or 118 feet from the miniature?

Comment: @static: 120 feet away from you, 118 feet away from the miniature.

Answer (score 1):

You consider the similar triangles  with the proportionality of $\frac {1}{60} $

$$\frac {x}{x+z}=\frac {1}{60}$$

Cross multiply and solve for $z$.

The answer is $$z=59x$$

Comment: Ok, yes I am right then that although the mini is at x, x is also defined as the distance from the viewer (me) to the mini. So any distance I stand from the mini must then be multiplied by 59 to place the real at the exact apparent size as the mini. Is this correct? I have been neglecting to include my distance to the miniature.

Comment: @s Yes, you are correct. We need to consider the viewer distance as well.